# Why can't parameters be null or empty strings when compared in a SELECT in PG?

Tags: postgresql, php

This is very strange. For a very long time, I've been `INSERT`ing parameters into PG queries from PHP like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ($1);
```

The $1 can be a boolean null or an empty string. Works perfectly.

Now, I'm "suddenly" getting errors, probably because I've never happened to encountered this situation before:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column <> $1;
```

If $1 is either null or an empty string, I get:

```
pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  there is no parameter $1
```

At first, I thought it might be logically related to the `<>` operator, but this also gives the very same error:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = $1;
```

I have foggy memories of `NULL` being annoyingly "special case" in PG, but even empty strings? And why specifically for `SELECT`s but not `INSERT`s?

Comment: To me it smells like a PHP problem. Not a SQL problem.

Comment: Supplying NULL as parameter is different from not supplying the parameter.

Comment: Show the PHP code.